# EL expression evaluation time on a JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, el

If I have a check box component and a corresponding instance variable on the backing bean, and a submit button with a corresponding action method. If the user checked the box, the variable should be set to `true`.

My Question, will that variable set to `true` when the user checked it or when the user press submit button?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box the submit button will send the request to the server which will update your server-side component variable.

But you can actually AJAXify your components quite easily (especially using JSF2), and can achieve an instant update of the server-side component. [Some component libraries](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectBooleanCheckbox.jsf) provide this for you built-in.